# Distance measures for binary data

Tags: euclidean-geometry, binary, data-analysis

I was wondering what are some good distance measures for binary data that have the following properties. I know that there are measures like the Jaccard index and the Dice Index, but they don't exactly suit my needs.

```
v1 = [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
v2 = [1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

v1' = [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
v2' = [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
```

v1 and v2 I would call 'similar', whereas v1' and v2' are very different. Basically, I want the distance measure to be able to describe the change distribution of the 1s throughout the array. if that changes substantially, then the distance should be high, otherwise low.

Is there a distance measure like this that exists? Thanks!

Comment: just an idea: the minimum primitive permutations to turn the one into the other (might be crap, just the first thing that came to my mind)

Comment: Compute the vectors of cumulative partial sums of each vector.  Subtract the one of these from the other.  Sum the squares of these differences.  This is inspired by the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test (which would just use the max of the result of the subtraction, instead of computing sums of squares...).

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Earth mover's distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover's_distance) (or Wasserstein metric).